# How do I set up dynamic imports correctly (for beyond localhost)?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, meteor, dynamic-import

I followed https://docs.meteor.com/packages/dynamic-import.html to set up dynamic imports, and it works fine on localhost.

For context, I am creating a blog (Meteor/React/Apollo) which renders MDX files, and these files need to be imported, so I have a list of all my posts as such:

```
import("./imports/posts/61a000d03a1931b8819dc17e.mdx")
import("./imports/posts/619cae2f03f4ff710aa3d980.mdx")
import("./imports/posts/619e002d386ebf2023ea85c3.mdx")
import("./imports/posts/619fff7c5b312d7622acda86.mdx")
```

I have a Post.jsx component:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react"
import { useHistory, useParams } from "react-router-dom"
import { useQuery } from "@apollo/client"
import { GET_POST_ID } from "../../api/posts/queries"

const Post = () => {
    const Post = useRef()
    const history = useHistory()
    const { slug } = useParams()
    const [loadedPost, setLoaded] = useState(false)
    const [viewer, showViewer] = useState(false)
    const open = () => showViewer(true)
    
    const { data, loading, error } = useQuery(GET_POST_ID, { variables: { slug }})
    
    if (loading) return null
    if (error) {
        console.log(error)
        return null
    }

    import(`./posts/${data._id}.mdx`).then(MDX => {
        Post.current = MDX.default
        setLoaded(true)
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })

    return loadedPost ? (
        <>
        <div className="postContent">
            <div className="markdownOverride markdown-body">
                <Post.current />
            </div>
        </div>
        </>
    ) : null
}

export default Post
```

This works well and good on my local network. However, if I attempt to access it from outside my local network, an error is thrown in the console that all the blog modules are not found. The Apollo/GraphQL portion works fine, but the actual module can't be imported.

How do I get this to work outside of localhost?

Thanks.

EDIT: The error messages are, for each post:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot find module '/imports/posts/61a000d03a1931b8819dc17e.mdx`
```

And when I load the actual post page:

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

Comment: You need to share the error thrown.

Comment: @ThomasAumaitre - I updated the main post with the errors, but they aren't very descriptive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that I needed to specify the `ROOT_URL` correctly when initializing Meteor. With an ngrok http tunnel on port 3000 pointing to `https://some-hash.ngrok.io`, I had to start Meteor with: `ROOT_URL="https://some-hash.ngrok.io" meteor`. When I do this, I can access it fine and everything loads from my local IP and the ngrok URL, but I can't seem to load it up from localhost (it times out).

Specifying my local or public IP did not work, I could not get it to load through any of those methods.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't your error thrown by `console.log(err)` ?

```
    import(`./posts/${data._id}.mdx`).then(MDX => {
        Post.current = MDX.default
        setLoaded(true)
    }, (err) => {
        console.log(err) // <---- here
    })
```

This means your path isn't right for `/imports/posts/61a000d03a1931b8819dc17e.mdx`.

To me you can't use changing parameters when doing dynamic imports.
`./posts/${data._id}.mdx`, because your `meteor` or `webpack` compilation needs to treat all the `data._id`s avalaible in your database in order to compile and prepare the file...

This might be why it works in development mode but not in production.

You can just do dynamic imports of modules or components (already compiled), no more to me. Take a look at your output compilation bundles, and try to find where are your components...

Comment: You can use changing parameters, because I have imported all of them into a file as I explained in the beginning of my post (it's also stated in the documentation link). When I try with an absolute path rather than relative, it doesn't compile and says it can't find the module.

Comment: If you imported all your files in a folder, it means filenames have to be hard-coded in your Post.jsx component, then you make if conditions to trigger the dynamic import aimed.

Comment: How you want webpack to compile this import(`./posts/${data._id}.mdx`) ? your compilation is blind of all your files.

Comment: Yes, that is what is happening. But it's not if conditions, it's based on the slug from the URL. For example, if you go to myblog.com/blog/example-post, it queries the database for the post ID matching the slug "example-post", and returns the post ID, and then it has to import "/imports/posts/<postID>.jsx". All of this works fine on localhost and within my own network. There's nothing wrong with dynamic imports on my own network. It's only when I access it from outside my local network, then the dynamic imports fail.

Comment: It compiles it from the first file I mentioned where everything is hardcoded.

Comment: Try to run your Meteor app in production mode, and access it from outside your local network. Are you using ngrok to make an http tunnel ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using ngrok for a http tunnel, that's how I've been testing it. And running it in production mode doesn't make a difference unfortunately.

Comment: the path isn't the same is it normal ? `import("./imports/posts/61a000d03a1931b8819dc17e.mdx")` vs. `import(`./posts/${data._id}.mdx`)` ?

Comment: That's fine, it points to the same file. I figured it out as I had to specify the `ROOT_URL` correctly when starting Meteor.